# Как отключить NAT на Oracle Cloud?

Tags: nat, облако

Возникла проблема, может среди кого то из вас есть те, кто работали с Oracle Cloud, ну не суть, в общем, есть программа которая принимает клиентов, но требует что бы NAT`а не было, а на Oracle Cloud он по умолчанию есть, как его отключить что бы виртуальная машина не была защищена NAT?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Я искал полгода назад - не нашел способа. В большинстве случаев нужно просто открыть порты. Попробуй разобраться что за программа и что ей на самом деле нужно.

Comment: Программа - pptpd, почему то не подключается, так называемое вечное подключение.